# How can I display the desired field name?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a question about Prometheus&Grafana: I have configured the Prometheus panel and want to display the up status of all services. But I found that the red box is not just PromQL, especially I want to get the job name in the blue box, how do I configure Legend?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdSsU.png)

The effect I want to achieve is: each box only displays JobName. thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to replace the `{{hostname}}` with `{{job}}` in the Legend section.

Comment: OMG，You're awesome，3Q